# Convert Visual Studio Solution and Project Files to DDK Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, wdk

I know products (such as VisualDDK) exist to use Visual Studio as a front end while using the DDK to build a project but I have the exact opposite question.

Are there tools to take an already existing Visual Studio `*.sln` and `*vcproj` files and generate `dirs` and `sources` files that can be used with the DDK?

I am interested in Visual Studio 2008 and above products.

Comment: I don't know if there are tools to do that, but if not, the solution and project files are XML, so it shouldn't be difficult to write one yourself.

Comment: That's a good point.  If I don't solve my problem some other way that's what I'll do.

Comment: If VS2012 fits your needs, you don't need any frontend, driver development support is built-in.

Comment: So I should have been a little more verbose with my question.  A real world example would be taking the source tree for a project like Apache Xerces and being able to use the DDK to build it completely.